# Efficient Deep copy in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, deep-copy

I want to deep copy an array of integers in NodeJS.
The first method I tried is

```
obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

However, it is so slow because it is a big array.

Now I am using

```
var l = obj1.length;
while (l--){
  obj2.push(obj1[l]);
}
```

Though it is much faster, I am wondering if there exist better solutions?
Thank you all!

Comment: What exactly does a "deep copy" of a simple array of integers mean? What would be the difference from a shallow copy ?

Comment: @adneo. I need use two different array (original order and sorted)

Comment: @LuyaoWang Why not just get a sorted array?

Comment: @stdop sort sorts in place

Comment: because I need some information of the original position of the original array later...

Comment: What's the content of the array? Primitives or objects?

Comment: In 2023, use `structuredClone` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/122704#122704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an array, did you try just

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice(0);
```

It does create a shallow copy, but for an array containing just primitive integers it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Arguments of slice are [optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), so `arr1.slice()` would do just fine.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев - and still I decided to add `0` as an argument, to make it clear that we're slicing from the beginning.

Comment: Why not explicitly set both indices then?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев - because according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the first argument isn't optional, only the second one is.

Comment: @adeneo you show docs for **string**, for an array the first argument is [optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: @isvforall - yeah, thought I was clever there and noone would notice, but both arguments are optional. Most of the time though you'll see `slice(0)` for arrays, probably because it's so common to add the zero whenever you use `slice()` as it's needed for strings, and I always add it without even thinking about it. It doesn't really matter, if you leave it out, the engine will just insert a zero for you, same thing as writing yourself.

Comment: Question clearly states "deep copy"

Answer (score 1):

you can also make it like

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    brr = arr.map(e => e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains numbers only (it won't to work if your array contains arrays), you could use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function without arguments

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = arr1.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a sorted array and save the information on the position of the element in the original array:

0) The original array:

```
var obj1 = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5, 0, 200, 30];
```

1) It is necessary to keep the original position:

```
var index = Object.keys( obj1 ).sort( function(a, b) {
  return obj1[a] - obj1[b];
});

// >> ["5", "0", "1", "2", "4", "7", "3", "6"]
```

2) Get a sorted array:

```
var obj2 = obj1.sort( function(a, b) {
  return a-b;
});

// >> [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 30, 100, 200]
```

3) Find the original position of the element with new index '0':

```
var originalIndex = index[0];

// >> "5"
```